# Determinant of a matrix with cofactor expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have this question here:

> Suppose that $A$ is an $(n,n)$-matrices, $n \geq 3$, with $\det(A)=5$ and whose $(2,3)$-minor $M_{2,3}(A)$ equals $12$. Let $S_{2,3}$ be the $(n,n)$-matrix all whose entries are $0$, except the entry
>   in position $(2,3)$ equals $2$. With $B:=(A+S_{2,3})$, find $\det(B)$.

The problem is that I am not sure how to go about this. I know for a fact that if $C=A+B$ in general, then $\det(C) \neq \det(A) + \det(B)$ so thus:

$\det(B) = \det(A+S_{2,3})$

I tried a sample matrix:

If $A=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 1 \\ 4 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

The determinant of this matrix is $5$ and the minor $M_{2,3}(A)$ is $A=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1\\ 4 & 4\end{bmatrix}$. The determinant of this minor is $12$.

$S_{2,3} = A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $

Thus, $A + S_{2,3} = B =\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 4 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. The determiant of this matrix gives $-19$. However, is there a better way of doing this in general? I don't think using specific matrices is the best idea.

Comment: You could check out LU decomposition, where te determinant is the product of the L or U diagonal. This is a fast in general, the Laplace expansion is heavely computational for general cases.

Comment: We didn't learn that. EDIT: We covered vector motion, complex numbers, matrix addition/subtraction, multiplication, RREF, and determinants along with their properties.

Comment: Did you arrive at a conclusion?

Comment: Hi yes. I did it a little differently but I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A faster way then using the Laplace expansion (cofacter expansion), would be first using row operations and then take the determinant in REF. A determinant of a triangular matrix is just the product of the diagonal. Hope this may help.